# How to add <p> after table? (php / JS / wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I would like to add p tage or line break after table, so that contents in table and div can display in two lines.
At the moment they display in one line which is very messy (i.imgur.com/7cnQhou.jpg).
Would you please let me know how to do it using php or JS?

```html
<div class="woocommerce-variation">
        <input type="hidden" id="thwepof_product_fields" name="thwepof_product_fields" value="test2">
        <table class="thwepo-extra-options thwepo_variable" cellspacing="0">
               <tbody><tr class=""><td class="label leftside"></td>
                      <td class="value leftside">
                      <input type="text" id="test2" class="thwepof-input-field">
                      </td></tr>
               </tbody>
         </table>
         <div class="quantity">
             <input type="number" id="quantity_60" class="input-text qty" inputmode="numeric">
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why adding tags, when you could style it with css like `<table style="margin-bottom:1rem">`?

Comment: I'm using plugins, that's how the plugins work

Comment: Use CSS, that's how the web works.

Answer (score 0):

`table` and `div` tag are both block level element. They display in two lines in default.

Below is the result of running your code.

[image: code running result]

Comment: It should be, but actually they are not : https://i.imgur.com/7cnQhou.jpg

Comment: May be the class attributes change the style. You can inspect them in browser development mode.